# Canvas.SendWillRenderCanvases() loads CPU

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have game that simulates work of messanger, so there are messages added to the window along the game. But when I create the message prefab and add it to the window I can see the CPU spike, and profiler shows me this

[image]

So why the LayoutRebuilder.Rebuild() and the Graphic.Rebuild() eat so much CPU?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the size of your prefab that you are adding, when you instantiate it, unity has to go through and recalculate all of the sizes for the prefab and fill the meshes. If you were to use less layout groups it would reduce the layout time, but the graphic rebuild can only be reduced by having less items to display.

If you want to see what happens when those things get called, you can view the [source](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/0155c39e05ca5d7dcc97d9974256ef83bc122586/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/CanvasUpdateRegistry.cs?at=5.2&fileviewer=file-view-default) here which may give you a better understanding of how to optimize your specific prefab

Comment: my prefab is really have lots of objects with Layout Group, thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

When I disabled Pixel Perfect on the canvas the frame rate drop went away.